# Open Firewall For Specific IP Address

Tags: ssh, iptables, firewall

I am currently trying to connect a website application on VPS-1 to a media server on VPS-2...

I can open the 3 ports needed which are 1935, 1936 and 5080 using ufw allow PORTNUMBER and the connection is made ok.

But if I close the ports on the firewall and use the following command to allow VPS-1 Ip address to connect in the iptables I cant make a connection.

The commands I am using are:

```
sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 187.147.197.177 -p tcp --destination-port 1935 -j ACCEPT

sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 187.147.197.177 -p tcp --destination-port 1936 -j ACCEPT

sudo /sbin/iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -s 187.147.197.177 -p tcp --destination-port 5080 -j ACCEPT
```

I have also tried the following ccommands:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 187.147.197.177 --dport 5080 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 187.147.197.177 --dport 1935 -j ACCEPT
iptables -I INPUT -p tcp -s 187.147.197.177 --dport 1936 -j ACCEPT
```

But neither allow VPS-2 to connect.

I'm completely new to iptables and so I don't fully understand what they do. But according to google searches they are supposed to work?

And pointers would be appreciated as I would like the ports closed except for VPS-2 being able to access VPS-1.

Thanks

Comment: Without the overall context of your entire iptables rule set, we are unable to answer. Do: `sudo iptables -v -x -n -L` and add it to your question. We also need some idea of the layout of your computers and network. Like where are vps-2 and vps-1 and any router or gateway with respect to each other. If I had to guess, I would guess that ufw is blocking the packets before your allow rules.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Its late now so I will look into this in the morning. Thanks.